# Cache is removing after add object to cache

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, web-config

I develop asp.net web forms application in VS2012 a I have one project with Web.App and one project is a Class Library.
In a class library i reading configuration from web.config (in a project is a lot of app settings like path for menu file, log file etc...) and in this assembly i have a class for caching and logging events to file.

This is a part of cache class:

```
public static class MyCache
{
    public const String CACHE_MENU_USER = "CACHE_MENU_USER_{0}";
    public const String CACHE_LOG_FILE_PATH = "LOG_FILE_PATH";
    public static void AddToCache(String cacheKey, Object value, DateTime absoluteExpiration, bool loggToFile = true)
    {

        HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add(cacheKey,
                                      value,
                                      null,
                                      absoluteExpiration,
                                      Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
                                      CacheItemPriority.High,
                                      (k, v, r) => //key, value, reason of remove from cache
                                      {
                                          String reasonOfRemove = String.Empty;
                                          switch (r)
                                          {
                                              case CacheItemRemovedReason.DependencyChanged:
                                                  reasonOfRemove = String.Format("CacheItemRemovedReason.DependencyChanged");
                                                  break;

                                              case CacheItemRemovedReason.Expired:
                                                  reasonOfRemove = String.Format("CacheItemRemovedReason.Expired");
                                                  break;

                                              case CacheItemRemovedReason.Removed:
                                                  reasonOfRemove = String.Format("CacheItemRemovedReason.Removed");
                                                  break;

                                              case CacheItemRemovedReason.Underused:
                                                  reasonOfRemove = String.Format("CacheItemRemovedReason.Underused");
                                                  break;
                                          }

                                          AppConfiguration.Logger.WriteMessage(String.Format("Key {0} was removed for reason: {1}", cacheKey, reasonOfRemove));
                                      });

        if (loggToFile)
            AppConfiguration.Logger.WriteMessage(String.Format("Insert cache key {0} from now to: {1}", cacheKey, absoluteExpiration));
    }
}
```

AppConfiguration is a static class with static properties with values from web.config.
Logger is a instance of Logger class.

In global.asax is a piece of code:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AppConfiguration.ReadConfiguration();
        AppConfiguration.Logger.WriteMessage("Start app");
    }
    protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AppConfiguration.Logger.WriteMessage("End app");
    }
```

Problem is, that App_Start is called on every request a inserted value to cache is immediately removed...

this is a part of log file:

10.8.2013 17:14:22: Start app.

10.8.2013 17:14:23: Insert cache key  CACHE_MENU_USER_DEMO\Administrator from now to: 8/17/2013 5:14:23 PM

10.8.2013 17:14:23: Key CACHE_MENU_USER_DEMO\Administrator was removed for reason: CacheItemRemovedReason.Removed

10.8.2013 17:14:23: End app.

a this is repeated with every request.

I was trying start application in IIS Express, i trying start application in server (IIS7, Windows server 2008 R2) and it is still the same...

Any idea what is wrong with cache and global.asax?
Thanks

**EDIT:**
**Problem solved. More is in comments from FlopScientist**

Comment: Show your function where you are  adding items to cache. I mean where you are calling the above method of your MyCache class

Comment: You're right, I overlooked this. Thank you. problem solved

Comment: The answer was not clear. What exactly did you change? I'm having a similar problem.